# Selector parameter changed but render does not get called

Tags: javascript, react-redux, reselect

```
//Reducer
const initialState = {
error: false,
fetching: false,
myData: []
}

export const getDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.MyData.fetch.request:
        return { ...state,
              fetching: true,
              error: false,
              myData: initialState.myData
            }

    case ActionTypes.MyData.fetch.success:
        return {
            ...state,
            myData: action.payload
            fetching: false,
            error: false
        }

    case ActionTypes.MyData.fetch.error:

        return { 
              ...state,
              error: true,
              fetching: false
            }
        }

export const getError = (state) => get(state, 'myData.error', false);

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
          return getMyData(state);
        }

        export const getMyData = createSelector(
          [getClientId, getFetching, getError],
          (clientId, fetching, error) => {
            console.log("in selector:", fetching, error)
            const state = store.getState();
            const myData = getData(state);

            let hasErrorOrNoData = error ? error : myData.length === 0;

            hasErrorOrNoData = fetching ? false : hasErrorOrNoData;
            console.log("in selector hasErrorOrNoData:", hasErrorOrNoData)

            return {
              error,
              fetching,
              hasErrorOrNoData,
              myData
            }
          }
        )
        export const DataTable = ({
          error,
          fetching,
          hasErrorOrNoData,
          myData
        }) => {
          console.log("in component this gets called only once")
          return ( <
            componentX rows = {
              myData
            }
            fetching = {
              fetching
            }
            error = {
              hasErrorOrNoData
            }
            errorComponent = { < NoDataMessage
              isError = {
                error
              }
              />
            }
            />
          )
        }
```

**Question**: Initially, the value of error is false, fetching is true. Later fetching is false and error is true (as the API call failed). Even though the select parameters' value changed, why the rendering is not happening? I put a console.log in render to check, but that got executed only once.

**FYI**: The change in fetching and clientId does fires render, it's only error which does not fire.

Adding reducer code

Comment: is that all the code? did you connect DataTable to redux?

Comment: Yes, I did the connection, but not sure if is it worth putting all the codes here. I believe I am missing something around selector method or mapStatToProps.

Comment: show your getError selector

Comment: Added as first line of the code.

Comment: Also added the reducer

Answer (score 0):

The unique way your code is not being updated is your **props are not changing**.

See this test:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-mcclintock-rhwt9?fontsize=14

Go to:

```
function reducer(state = { test: { fixed: "fixed", error: false } }, action) {
  return { test: { fixed: "fixed", error: !state.test.error } };
}
```

and change: `error: !state.test.error` to `error: state.test.error` and the update will stop.

**EDIT**

In your reducer I see:

```
case ActionTypes.MyData.fetch.error:

        return { 
              ...state,
              error: true,
              fetching: false
            }
        }
```

And the **getError selector is**

`export const getError = (state) => get(state, 'myData.error', false);`

But in your initial state: myData is an array so, `myData.error` will not exists. Your `getError` selector will be returning always false.

Try to change the selector to:

`export const getError = (state) => state.error;`

Comment: My problem is that it is not updating. It just does not re-render even though in reducer I am changing the value of error (which I can see in console.log)

Comment: Nice, but still same result, I can see that on error the flag has been changed in Redux store and I am also getting the correct flag using getError, but still it is not rendering.

Comment: @TechTurtle update your question with a minimum reproducible case. without see a global view I can't help you. BTW if not updating your props are not being changed.

Comment: if I put less code then people are asking to show more codes. In one line the scenario is that - even tough my input param ("error" in this case) gets changed the render part is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

The real culprit was `shouldComponentUpdate`, the condition written within it was not allowing render.
I believe the document should mention the same - just to give a hint.